# Get target URL when known a Redirect URL

Tags: php, curl

everybody.
I have a URL:

`http://www.baomoi.com/thanh-nien-tim-hieu-thong-tin-bau-cu-dai-bieu-quoc-hoi/r/19140036.epi`

If I browse the URL by a browser,  the URL will be redirected  and move to  a new URL as below:

```
http://www.tienphong.vn/gioi-tre/thanh-nien-tim-hieu-thong-tin-bau-cu-dai-bieu-quoc-hoi-993059.tpo
```

I want to code a PHP function to get the New URL. 
I read a lot of section using curl, but I only get the URL instead of the New URL.
I am looking forward to hearing your reply.
Thank you!

Comment: What is your actual code ?

Comment: The URL is changed in javascript. You won't be able to retrieve it with a simple cURL request.

Comment: Thus, may you have any guideline for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Permanent redirection using `header()`.

Put following code in your file from where you want to redirect.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.tienphong.vn/gioi-tre/thanh-nien-tim-hieu-thong-tin-bau-cu-dai-bieu-quoc-hoi-993059.tpo"); 
exit();
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect, I want to code a function as below:
Get_Target_URL("http://www.baomoi.com/..."). The result I want be "http://tienphong.nv".